# Can't find keychain using 'security' framework

Tags: swift

I'm saving some user data of the same app in keychains. But I can't find where they are stored. Is there a way to find the path of the keychains?

```swift
class KeychainManager {
    enum KeychainError: Error {
        case duplicateEntry
        case unknown(OSStatus)
    }
static func save(service: String, account: String, password: Data) throws {
        // service, account, password, class, data
        let query: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kSecAttrService as String: service as AnyObject,
            kSecAttrAccount as String: account as AnyObject,
            kSecValueData as String: password as AnyObject,
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword
        ]
        let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
        guard status != errSecDuplicateItem else {
            throw KeychainError.duplicateEntry
        }
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            throw KeychainError.unknown(status)
        }
    }
}
func save(account: String, password: String) {
    
    do {
        try KeychainManager.save(
            service: "loseamp",
            account: account,
            password: password.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data())
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? There are powerful APIs to find items. By the way annotate `let query: [CFString: Any]` then you can delete **all** `as ...` casts in the dictionary literal. And you can replace also  `password.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data())` with `Data(password.utf8)` (no optional).

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, you can find the paths of all the currently searched keychains with `security list-keychains`. You can find the code that does this in [keychain_list.c](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/Security/blob/Security-60420.81.3/SecurityTool/macOS/keychain_list.c#L206-L245). The main functions are [SecKeychainCopySearchList](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1402440-seckeychaincopysearchlist) and [SecKeychainGetPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1401073-seckeychaingetpath).

Both of these functions are deprecated on Mac and unavailable on iOS. Generally you should not be querying for the specific paths except in Mac admin tools (in which case you will generally use the supported `security` interface rather than a programmatic interface). Not all "things in the keychain" are in a file at all. Some are stored in the [Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/protecting_keys_with_the_secure_enclave). You can get a reference to these items and use them in operations, but you cannot access their data.

Comment: I was trying to make the logic behind a register screen to work and I used a lot of test emails that got stored in keychains, and now I wanted to delete every email that's linked to that specific 'service'. I have a function that deletes a given email. But I used so many test email addresses that I forgot their name and now I am trying to make a function that deletes all of them at once.

Comment: You'll want SecItemCopyMatching with a query that matches the service and class with kSecMatchLimitAll. It'll return you all the items and you can delete them.